# Problem evaluating a command inside a string

Tags: bash

I'm trying to bind an espeak command to a key using [xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys). The idea is pretty simple: I press a given shortcut, and espeak reads what's on clipboard for me because sometimes I get somewhat lazy:

```
espeak -v us-mbrola-3 -s 250 "$(xclip -o)"
```

It works pretty fine on the terminal, but inside `.xbindkeysrc` it doesn't:

```
"espeak -v us-mbrola-3 -s 250 "$(xclip -o)""
    m:0xc + c:10
```

Problem is that it requires a [string](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Configuration) for the command, and I need those double quotes to evaluate the xclip command. Tried wrapping with '', but it doesn't work (It just reads "xclip" instead of evaluating).

Comment: Try to replace the `"$(xclip -o)"` for `'$(xclip -o)'` (double quote for single) or escape the double quote as`\"$(xclip -o)\"`. Does that work?

Comment: Nope, I think I have to use eval.

Comment: eval it will be :-)

Comment: Looking at espeak's manual I think you might have been able to use `xclip -o | espeak -v us-mbrola-3 -s 250`

Comment: @Aaron, it doesn't work. That command makes it speak the whole command itself, treating it as a literal, without evaluating the xclip and without feeding its output to espeak.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work using `eval`:

```
"eval `espeak -v us-mbrola-3 -s 250 "$(xclip -o)"`"
    m:0xc + c:10
```